# How to have Powershell read multiple values from a single CSV cell?

Tags: csv, powershell, permissions

I am trying to apply permissions to multiple folders at once. I have a .csv file with the folder paths in one column and the security groups in a second column. Most folders will have multiple groups with access. The .csv is in the following format:

```
folderpath        groupname
----------        ---------
C:\Folder1        Group1
C:\Folder2        Group2, Group3
```

My code will not currently apply the permissions because there are multiple values in some groupname cells. It will apply if only one group is listed.

```
#Specify CSV location
$csv = import-csv G:\testcsv.csv

#Start loop
foreach($masterlist in $csv)

{

$folderpath = $masterlist.folderpath
$groupname = $masterlist.groupname

#Apply permission to folderpath
add-ntfsaccess -path $folderpath -account $groupname -accessrights modify,synchronize

}
```

For example, if I run the above code, Group1 will successfully be given permission to C:\Folder1. But C:\Folder2 will have nothing applied because Group2 and Group3 are both in the same cell. Can I adjust my code without having to manually separate hundreds of these cells in the .csv?

Thank you for your help!!!!!

Comment: So you want to do `$groupname -split "," |%{add-ntfsaccess -path $folderpath -account $_.trim() -accessrights modify,synchronize}`

Answer (score 1):

just create inside loop foreach Group  :) simplest method

```
 #Start loop
foreach($masterlist in $csv)

{
$folderpath = $masterlist.folderpath
$groupnames = $masterlist.groupname -split ","

foreach ($group in $groupnames ) {

#Apply permission to folderpath
add-ntfsaccess -path $folderpath -account $group -accessrights modify,synchronize

}
}
```

this is adHoc response but i think you get the idea.